# Software like Evernote with Markdown

Tags: note-taking, markdown

I am looking for a Web and/or desktop app (Windows & Cloud sync) that behaves like **Evernote** but also has **Markdown** support. I searched but could not find anything useful.

Comment: [Marxico](http://marxi.co/) - the missing markdown editor for Evernote

Comment: @ṧнʊß Thanks. Better than what I was expecting. Make this your answer. I will mark it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [marxico](http://marxi.co/)

**Markdown editor with *Evernote integration and support***

#### Evernote Support:

- easily link from sidebar on the right
- one-click save (button 3rd from the right at the top right)

#### Features:

- Keyboard shortcuts, such as Ctrl+*I*, **B**, S (save) etc...
- Auto closes brackets, quotes () [] "" ''
- Syncs with Evernote
- Paste images via clipboard! (wish we had that in SE :)
- Very easy to use

[image]
[image]

(BTW I just copied and pasted the markdown from Marxico to here - same as SE, except for the picture :( - you can only see that in the screenshot above :))

Answer (score 0):

With [stack-edit](https://stackedit.io/editor) you can make your notes in markdown, including importing html from other web pages and then you can synchronize your documents to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/), [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or a CouchDB instance or you can publish to a number of locations.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not personally used, [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/) has a great reputation among note takers and Markdown users.

It's closed-source, but offers perpetual free license for personal use, and any data is stored on your computer and stays with you.

[image]

Cloud sync feature is [offered](https://obsidian.md/pricing) at US$10 per month, but I wouldn't bother with that when I already have OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

[Notion.so](https://www.notion.so) is an online Markdown notebook service. It's the closest competitor to Evernote I've seen, and it offers importing from Evernote (surprise!).

It's an online Markdown-based notebook that organizes your notes into pages. It's a [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) so your data is stored on Notion's servers, and syncs seamlessly across all devices. It also provides sharing and real-time collaboration features just like Google Docs. Note pages can be shared to the public internet, like [mine](https://ibug.notion.site).

In case you need to take out your data, you can export your content as either Markdown + assets, or as a PDF.

Client software is available for browsers (just open [notion.so](https://www.notion.so)), Windows, macOS, iOS and Android.