# Evernote with custom properties. Notion with full offline support

Tags: database, note-taking, django, rtf, evernote

I need a desktop RDBMS to conveniently manage a bundle of rich text notes -- CRUD, adding tags, search inside notes, backups, etc. In a way, I need a light, abridged, desktop only version of Evernote that can also add metadata ("custom fields" or "properties" in Notion) to the rich-text notes.

Critical functionality:

1. Windows
2. CRUD
3. Rich text editor
4. Pasting formatted text and images from clipboard preserves formatting
5. Using tags
6. Adding custom fields to the notes (aka Notion's "properties")
7. Searching inside notes with real-time suggestions
8. Working offline seamlessly (in fact, at this point I'm not interested in online/mobile at all)
9. Backups

Declined candidates:

**[Evernote](https://evernote.com)**
[Does not allow](https://discussion.evernote.com/forums/topic/104378-add-custom-field/) to add custom fields to the note entries -- those little things Notion has and calls them "properties".

**[Notion](https://www.notion.so)**
[Does not support](https://www.reddit.com/r/Notion/comments/axjetu/notion_offline_mode/) offline working with your notes.

**[KeepNote](http://keepnote.org/)**
Severely outdated

**[TagSpaces](https://www.tagspaces.org/)**
Very different concept

**[Simplenote](https://simplenote.com/)**
No rich text;
No custom fields

**[OneNote](https://simplenote.com/)**
Similar to Evernote

**[Keep](https://keep.google.com)**
Similar to Simplenote

**[Bear](https://bear.app)**
Can't assess, for Mac users only

**[Zim](https://zim-wiki.org/)**
No custom fields;
Pastes don't keep source formatting;
No in-text images

Very far from what I look for are [CintaNotes](http://cintanotes.com/), [NixNote](http://nixnote.org/), [Turtl](https://turtlapp.com/), [GNotes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dayup.gnotes), [Laverna](https://laverna.cc/).

As a raw idea -- can it be implemented with Django and where do you recommend I start? [Vibrato Notes](https://vibrato.app/) might be worth trying once deployed, if and when.

Any recommendations?

PS Similar queries:

- [Offline alternative to OneNote / Evernote](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/24747/offline-alternative-to-onenote-evernote)
- [Software like Evernote with Markdown](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14451/software-like-evernote-with-markdown)
- [Open source note-taking app with tagging](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34931/open-source-note-taking-app-with-tagging)
- [Now that Evernote free is limited to two devices, what should I switch to?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34250/now-that-evernote-free-is-limited-to-two-devices-what-should-i-switch-to)
- [An open alternative for Evernote?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35392/an-open-alternative-for-evernote)
- [Offline note taking app that preserves HTML formatting](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/37879/offline-note-taking-app-that-preserves-html-formatting)

Comment: Why desktop (instead of offline-first)?

Comment: Budget range....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/) in combination with the [dataview plugin](https://blacksmithgu.github.io/obsidian-dataview/) would work? This is how I think it scores on your requirements:

1. ✅ Windows - It has a [Windows app](https://obsidian.md/download).
2. ✅ CRUD - You can create, read, update and delete the notes and properties.
3. ❌ Rich text editor - As far as I know Obsidian only works with plain text Markdown files. They are *shown* with formatting, but editing is in plain text.
4. ❌ Pasting formatted text and images from clipboard preserves formatting - Same as above, editing happens in plain text only.
5. ✅ Using tags - [Tags](https://help.obsidian.md/Editing+and+formatting/Tags) can be added to each note.
6. ✅ Adding custom fields to the notes (aka Notion's "properties") - [Properties](https://help.obsidian.md/Editing+and+formatting/Properties)  can be added to each note.
7. ❌ Searching inside notes with real-time suggestions - [Search](https://help.obsidian.md/Plugins/Search) is available but I don't think it provides suggestions.
8. ✅ Working offline seamlessly (in fact, at this point I'm not interested in online/mobile at all) - You can store all your Markdown notes in an offline folder.
9. ✅ Backups - You can back-up your vault folder to any location you like.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at https://standardnotes.org? It meets most of the requirements I think, minus the requirement for custom fields. It being open source and able to build on top of it, with the extension system.

Comment: Thank you ZucchiniZe. However Standard Notes does not seem to offer anything useful above Evernote -- only privacy, maybe. Out of the box it has less useful features than Evernote -- eg. no rich text editor. And presence of custom note properties is critical -- it's the lack of those that pushes me to search for Evernote replacement.